# Pre-populate local Maven cache with specific dependencies

Tags: java, maven

It looks like `mvn install:install-file` is for downloading a jar to a specific location.

I just want to manually download some publicly accessible dependencies to my local Maven cache (specifically the help and versions plugin). It doesn't have to be specific versions, just the latest versions is fine

I want Maven to install them just like it would with the `install` goal but just execute this from command line without a pom. Is this possible?

Comment: Will this link help ? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: no i dont think thats what i want. these arent 3rd party artifacts and arent hosted locally and I dont want to download them to a specific location. these are publicly available in maven central and I want maven to download them like it does with the default install goal

Comment: Do you want to download a jar file to a specific location other than .m2 directory ?

Comment: nope to the default location. the same location running mvn install against a pom would put it- the users local repo

Comment: Could you maybe tell us a bit more about the problem you want to solve? Maybe there are other possible approaches as well.

Comment: `mvn install:install-file` is to install an artifact which is given on command line into the local repository (`$HOME/.m2/repository`)  not related to downloading at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want create a pom.xml then you can use [download-maven-plugin](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin)'s artifact goal as shown in the below example.

> You need pass **groupId**, **artifactId** and **version**. It
>   can't download the file if any one of these 3 are missing or not
>   matching with central repo. If you don't want to download pom file, you can ignore the second line.

Example:

```
mvn com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.4.2:artifact -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=1.2.4 -Dtype=jar -DoutputDirectory=C:\Temp

mvn com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.4.2:artifact -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=1.2.4 -Dtype=pom -DoutputDirectory=C:\Temp
```

This will download both JAR and POM files for log4j:log4j:1.2.4 from central repository to your local repository and also copies the files to *C:\Temp* folder. Once you are done downloading all the files, you can delete the Temp folder.